# Specify NotNull If Method Returns At All

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I'm using the new nullable reference types from C# 8 and I was wondering if it is possible to indicate that a parameter passed in is not null if the method returns at all.

I've found `[NotNullIf]` and `[DoesNotReturnIf]` but these appear to trigger off a method's return value and a specific `bool` parameter respectively.

Here is what I currently have:

```
public static bool RaiseIfNull([NotNullWhen(true)] object? thing) => RaiseIf(() => thing is null);
public static bool RaiseIf(Func<bool> predicate)
{
  if (predicate()) throw new HttpException(400);
  return true;
}
```

This seems good, but then when I call it - I still see warnings. (I also tried `RaiseIfNull([NotNullIfNotNull("thing")] object? thing)` and that didn't work.)

```
[HttpPost("{id}")]
public async Task Etc(string id, [FromBody] Dto data)
{
  HttpException.RaiseIfNull(data?.property);
  await DoEtc(id, data.property)); // warning here
}
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: This is not exactly what you need but I think it's worth noting that for type parameters, there is the `where T : notnull` constraint.

The type argument must be a non-nullable type. The argument can be a non-nullable reference type in C# 8.0 or later, or a not nullable value type. This constraint applies also to any class, interface, delegate, or array type.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Using a normal null-check**

First of all, `RaiseIfNull` doesn't offer something more than :

```
var value=data?.property ?? new HttpException(400);
```

Which the compiler can recognize. `RaiseIfNull` on the other hand hides what's actually going on. This code doesn't produce a warning:

```
class D
{
    public string? property{get;set;}
}


D? data=null;
var value=data?.property ?? throw new HttpException(400);
Console.WriteLine(value.Length);
```

**Unconditional Post-Condition and generics**

That said, the the correct argument to use is [`NotNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.notnullattribute?view=netcore-3.0) - after the method executes, the parameter is not null even if the type itself is nullable. That attribute can be applied to :

- Parameters
- Properties
- Fields and
- Return values

The methods can be made generic too, to avoid boxing structs into objects. To do that we need to specify whether the type is a class or struct, because the resulting concrete types are very different - a `string?` is still a string while an `int?` is a `Nullable<int>` :

```
public static bool RaiseIfNull<T>([NotNull] T? thing) 
    where T:class
    => RaiseIf(() => thing is null);

public static bool RaiseIfNull<T>([NotNull] T? thing) 
    where T:struct
    => RaiseIf(() => thing is null);
```

Given those methods, the following code won't generate a warning either :

```
D? data=null;
RaiseIfNull(data?.property);
Console.WriteLine(data.property.Length);
```

Finally, we can get rid of the return value:

```
public static void RaiseIfNull<T>([NotNull] T? thing) 
    where T:class
    => RaiseIf(() => thing is null);

public static void RaiseIfNull<T>([NotNull] T? thing) 
    where T:struct
    => RaiseIf(() => thing is null);
```

Comment: `RaiseIfNull()` makes sense and is useful, if this method creates a complex failure message or exception object, and if the check is executed at multiple places. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: `Parameter 'thing' must have a non-null value when exiting.` RaiseIfNull<T>. https://dotnetfiddle.net/xHB8Xs