# C# 8 Nullable Reference Types Nested Guard

Tags: c#, types, reference, nullable, guard

I've recently updated a project to utilize the C# 8 Nullable Reference Types feature. Everything in the solution works as expected, except for a custom Guard class that was written to reduce the number of keystrokes needed when creating Guard expressions. Here is a basic example of the Guard class:

```cs
public static partial class Guard
{
    public static void AgainstNull(object? value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("The value can not be null");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the test class:

```cs
public class Test
{
    public object? Data { get; set; }

    public void TestMethod()
    {
        Guard.AgainstNull(Data);

        //if (Data == null)
        //{
        //    throw new ArgumentNullException("Data can not be null.");
        //}

        var text = Data.ToString();
    }
}
```

Attempting to use the Guard class results in a "Dereference of a possibly null reference" error:

[image: Dereference of a possibly null reference]

However, if I use a traditional guard expression (if (Data == null)), the compiler is smart enough to infer that the Data property will not be null:

```cs
public class Test
{
    public object? Data { get; set; }

    public void TestMethod()
    {
        //Guard.AgainstNull(Data);

        if (Data == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Data can not be null.");
        }

        var text = Data.ToString();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use nested expressions / guard statements with the C# 8 Nullable Reference Types feature?

Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis

Comment: Not sure if this will work, i'm on mobile, but try `var text = Data.ToString()!;` ? with the `!` after ToString(). Give it a try. I think it's called **null suppression operator**. You can then in your testclass either instantiate it like this: `Guard.AgainstNull(Data!);` or use it like i suggested above.

Comment: Now that I think about it, you should do `Data!.ToString();` because you want to ensure that Data is not null. `!` has no effect on runtime (which is a good thing :) ), it only affects static evaluation. At run time, expression `Data!` evaluates to the result of the underlying expression of `Data`.

Let me know if it helped you and I can write up a more elaborate answer once I get to a computer.

Comment: @Joel, I apologize for the slow reply. SO automatically closed my question because it was already answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58279704/specify-notnull-if-method-returns-at-all

This answer was what I was looking for. I added the [NotNull] attribute to my Guard class and the static analysis began working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an equivalent approach to `if (Data == null)`.

You can simply use the `!` (null-forgiving/null suppression operator) on your object

*(Introduced in C# 8.0)*

If you are familiar with languages like TypeScript, you'll be familiar with its implications. If not, here's a quick rundown:

- Has no effect on runtime.
- Only affects the compiler's static flow analysis.
- `Data!` evaluates to the result of the underlying expression of `Data` at runtime.

So in your case, you should be able to do either of these:

```
Guard.AgainstNull(Data!);
```

Or

```
var text = Data!.ToString();
```

---

Here's a example following your example for further clarification

```
#nullable enable
public static partial class Guard
{
    public Guard(object? value) => Value = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));

    public object? Value { get; }
}


public class Test
{
    public object? Data { get; set; }
    public void TestMethod()
    { 
         Guard(Data!);
         var text = Data!.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the null condition operator when you call Data.ToString();

```
var text = Data?.ToString()
```