# How to tell C# nullable type checker that a variable cannot be null after a function call returns?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

## Short Version

How to make the C# nullable type checking compiler realize that the variable `customer` **cannot** be null after the call returns:

```
Constraints.NotNull(customer);
```

.NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZcgRCV

## Long Version

If i have code like:

```
#nullable enable

Customer? c;
...
Console.WriteLine(customer.FirstName);
```

The compiler will (correctly) warn me that `customer` might be null when i try to access `.FirstName`:

> customer.FirstName  ⇐ possible null dereference

## Guard Constraint

I want to perform a guard, or a constraint that will **tell** the C# 8 nullable type checker that the value **cannot** be null. I'll call a function that ***guarantess*** that the variable cannot be null after the function returns:

```
#nullable enable

Customer? customer;
...
Constraint.NotNull(customer, nameof(customer)); //*if* this function returns, customer is *definitely* not null
Console.WriteLine(customer.FirstName);
```

Where `Constraint.NotNull` is something like:

```
public static class Constraint
{
    public static void NotNull(Object? o, String msg="")
    {
       if (o == null) 
          throw new Exception("Object cannot be null "+msg);
    }
}
```

And the guard does its job; it raises an exception. But the compiler doesn't realize that `customer` cannot be null after `Constrant.NotNull` returns:

[image]

## Another Example

A better example, i came across in some old code:

```
Customer? currentCustomer;

//...

EnsureCurrentCustomer(); 

DoSomethingWithIt(currentCustomer); // guaranteed not null because EnsureCurrentCustomer did it,
             // but the compiler doesn't know that.
```

We need a way for `EnsureCurrentCustomer` to **tell** the C# 8 nullable type checker that the variable `currentCustomer` **cannot** be null after `EnsureCurrentCustomer` function returns.

How do?

---

- Attempt 1: Null forgiving (!) operator

  No. I want to work with the type system, not hide the land-mines ([as Microsoft reminds you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving))
- Attempt 2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58282043/12597 (gives its own error)
- Attempt 3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65076221/12597 (No, see #1)

ChatGPT says the only way to do it is to use the JetBrains `[NotNull]` constraint; which i don't have access to.

Comment: Why are you declaring it as a customer? rather than a plain customer (?)  The whole point of customer? is to say it might contain a null.

Comment: @LorenPechtel I'm declaring it as `Customer?` because it might contain a `null`.

Answer (score 1):

This is achieved using the `[NotNull]` annotation on the argument being verified in your guard-clause method. A good reference for this is in the [`ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull` static method](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/ArgumentNullException.cs#L59). The summary of the `NotNullAttribute` says:

> Specifies that an output will not be null even if the corresponding type allows it. Specifies that an input argument was not null when the call returns.

You can also refer to [xUnit's `Assert.NotNull` assertion](https://github.com/xunit/assert.xunit/blob/main/NullAsserts.cs#L26), which does the same thing.